# Issue while installing Mariadb on mcp8 through Docker

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am trying to install Mariadb on mcp8 through Docker. I have cloned Mariadb from GitHub using https://github.com/MariaDB/server.git.

Then I changed the directory to server and configured using `./configure` , followed with `make` and `make install`. This worked fine.

But while running make test, the `pcre_test` failed with the following message:

> Test 3: Locale-specific features (using 'fr_FR' locale)
>   Locale test did not run successfully. The output did not match
>   /server/pcre/testdata/testoutput3, /server/pcre/testdata/testoutput3A or /server/pcre/testdata/testoutput3B.
>   This may mean that there is a problem with the locale settings rather
>   than a bug in PCRE.

I search for the locale using `locale -a | grep fr_FR`, which shows me that it's there. Still the test fails.

Comment: you can tell me if you want any more clarification on this question

Comment: When you search for the locale, is it in your host or inside your container ? You have a great post about locale, locale-gen and so in docker at 

http://jaredmarkell.com/docker-and-locales/

Comment: I searched for the locale from the container..Will check the link given by you and update asap

Comment: Sorry but this link was not helpful..

Comment: So there is a bug in PCRE maybe ?